# Выгрузка файлов?

Tags: kohana, файлы

В общем есть ссылка на файл, возможно ли как-то сделать чтобы файл выгружался пользователю через вид?

напр.

```
$view = View::factory('myfileurl');
$this->template->content = $view;
```

В общем чтобы не по прямой ссылке переходить (а для этого я так понимаю header('Location: '.myfilurl) нужно ставить), а на том же роуте, одним словом в том же `action'e`.

Comment: паходу тупая затея, без `header('Location` никак.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью роутов это можно сделать!

```
Route::set('documents_download','qms/document/download(/<id>)', array('id' => '.*'))
    ->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'directory',
    'controller' => 'document',
    'action' => 'download',
));
```

в параметр id передаём, например, имя файла. По нему проверяем в базе реальную ссылку и отдаём пользователю полный адрес с заголовками, чтобы браузеры и менеджеры закачек правильно поняли что это за файл. У меня сделано так:

```
public function action_download()
    {
        $document = ORM::factory('qms_document')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', DB::expr("'%".UTF8::trim($this->request->param('id'))."%'"))
            ->find();

        if(!$document->loaded())
        {
            $view = View::factory('document/not_found');
            $this->template->set('content', $view);
        } else {

            $document->downloads++;
            $document->save();

            $absolute = URL::site(substr($document->link, 2), 'http');
            $headers = get_headers($absolute, 1);

            header("Content-type: ".Arr::get($headers, 'Content-Type'));
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$document->name);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Поставь в экшен

```
$file = "/home/viruskin/pron/sashagrey/4d3c227be6.720.mp4";
if (file_exists($file))
{
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
}
```